# UIImageview Programmatically in swift

Tags: cocoa-touch, swift

I'm just trying to create a **UIImage** View programmatically, I have a new view and I tried doing this

```
let imageName = "yourImage.png"
view.backgroundColor = UIColor.colorWithPatternImage(UIImage(named:imageName))
```

This code doesn't work. please help me as soon as possible

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you create a UIImage View Programmatically - Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26569371/how-do-you-create-a-uiimage-view-programmatically-swift)

Comment: Hi, we **want** to help you, but with "*This code doesn't work*" we don't have enough information. **How** does it not work? **What** happens? Also, writing "*please help me as soon as possible*" won't elicit answers any sooner...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is for image with 100 height and 100 width:

```
var imageViewObject :UIImageView
imageViewObject = UIImageView(frame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100));
imageViewObject.image = UIImage(named:"imageName.png")
self.view.addSubview(imageViewObject)
```

To resize the image to fit the view frame:

```
    imageViewObject.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleToFill
 or
    imageViewObject.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
or
    imageViewObject.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
```

Answer (score 4):

First create UIImageView , add image in UIImageView with frame and than give image Name.The following code help you.

```
var imageView : UIImageView
imageView  = UIImageView(frame:CGRectMake(10, 50, 100, 300));
imageView.image = UIImage(named:"image.jpg")
self.view.addSubview(imageView)
```

Comment: according question its true