# Programmatically loading images with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage

I am trying to load and display images (UIImage with Swift 3) dynamically
but I seem to be missing something (it's not working!) probably simple.

I am using UILabels for text descriptions and when images exist to replace the descriptions I want to load and display them. What I have so far is:

When images are found to exist, connect the images with UIImage items:

```
var rb1image: UIImage = UIImage(named: image1)!
var rb2image: UIImage = UIImage(named: image2)!
```

Connect the UIImage items with UIImageView items:

```
var rb1img = UIImageView(image: rb1image)
var rb2img = UIImageView(image: rb2image)
```

Position and size the UIImageView items using the UILabel positions and image sizes:

```
rb1img.frame = CGRect(x: rbanslabel1.frame.origin.x, y: rbanslabel1.frame.origin.y, width: (rb1img.image?.size.width)!, height: (rb1img.image?.size.height)!)
rb2img.frame = CGRect(x: rbanslabel2.frame.origin.x, y: rbanslabel1.frame.origin.y, width: (rb1img.image?.size.width)!, height: (rb1img.image?.size.height)!)
```

Labels display just fine but the images aren't being displayed. I am expecting the images to appear where the labels are.

Any hints as to what I am missing? Thanks in advance :-)

--- Added full code listing ---

The full code is:

```
if exists(image1) {            
    var rb1image: UIImage = UIImage(named: image1)!
    var rb2image: UIImage = UIImage(named: image2)!
    var rb1img = UIImageView(image: rb1image)
    var rb2img = UIImageView(image: rb2image)            
    rb1img.frame = CGRect(x: rbanslabel1.frame.origin.x, y: rbanslabel1.frame.origin.y, width: (rb1img.image?.size.width)!, height: (rb1img.image?.size.height)!)
    rb2img.frame = CGRect(x: rbanslabel2.frame.origin.x, y: rbanslabel1.frame.origin.y, width: (rb1img.image?.size.width)!, height: (rb1img.image?.size.height)!)
```

I must have been tired last night because today in the sidebar I saw this: [How do you create a UIImage View Programmatically - Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26569401/3803839).

I was missing:

```
view.addSubview(rb1img)
view.addSubview(rb2img)
```

Comment: you should post the full code in order to clarify what you are doing

Comment: Try a few things. (1) Set a breakpoint to make sure you are actually setting up the image views with something. (2) But more, do something different with your image view frames - your code is setting alarms off for me. If your image view origin is the same as the label, there's a good chance that you are in fact displaying the image but it is covered up by the label.

Comment: Did you spot your mistake? I strongly suspect that you have defined your uiimageviews in IB but your code replaces them; therefore they don't appear because they're not in the view hierarchy anymore (and if they're weak, they're even discarded immediately). I can elaborate if you wish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing:

```
view.addSubview(rb1img)
view.addSubview(rb2img)
```

I found the answer in the response to a different question: [How do you create a UIImage View Programmatically - Swift.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26569401/3803839)

Note: I have posted the solution, which I previously added as an edit to the question, because it was showing as unanswered.