# How do I directly assign an image to a UIImageView?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

I have an imageView with an outlet called humanEyesUIIV and now simply want to add an image programmatically. I use the following code:

```
humanEyesArray = [
        UIImage(named: "humanEyes0")!
        ]

   humanEyesUIIV.image? = humanEyesArray[0]
```

No error shows and the simulator runs fine, but the picture doesn't show up for some reason. I have looked at this thread and the code there works fine:

[How do you create a UIImage View Programmatically - Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26569371/how-do-you-create-a-uiimage-view-programmatically-swift)

```
let imageName = "yourImage.png"
let image = UIImage(named: imageName)
let imageView = UIImageView(image: image!)

imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 200)
view.addSubview(imageView)
```

The problem is just that I want to insert the imageView in the UI and handle its constraints and so on there, then simple add the image programatically. Any ideas what's wrong with my code?

Comment: Have you checked if your image is `nil`? This is the behavior you'll see if `UIImage(named:"humanEyes0")!` is (a) syntactically correct but (b) the actual image name  is misspelled or has the wrong file type or cannot be found. Try setting a breakpoint and before that check what the first element in your array is. NOTE: Your syntax looks good.

Comment: Also make sure your constraints are correct and the imageView has a frame. A simple way to check this might be to give the imageView a background color and check if it shows up.

Comment: Although if you’re trying to use the size of the image to intrinsically size the imageView it may not have a size if there is a problem with the image. How have you added the imageView to the view hierarchy?

Comment: Thank you for your replies :) I checked and the image did have a value (and the image did show when I tried using the code from the other thread). I also checked the imageView and it had a value. Gave it a bg color and it showed in the simulator. Still no image though :( I did a print() of the image and the image View and it came back: [<UIImage: 0x6040000b0500>, {280, 280}, 
<UIImageView: 0x7fba95708cc0; frame = (47 20; 280 280); alpha = 0.4; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x60400003d580>>

Comment: Have you tried displaying another test image? Is the alpha 0.4 on purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, solved it now by removing the question mark :) So, instead of:

```
   humanEyesUIIV.image? = humanEyesArray[0]
```

I now have:

```
   humanEyesUIIV.image = humanEyesArray[0]
```

That's it! :) Thanks for helping me out :)

Answer (score 1):

To get you going, just put a simple UIImageView in the scene in storyboard.  Make it large, ensure you have four constraints, and put in an image of a cat or something.

Now add an `@IBOutlet var test UIImageView!` and connect it.

Next add some code like test.alpha = 0.1 just to absolutely check you are OK so far.

Finally, just go `test.image =` .. your image.

This will allow you to test one problem at a time.